# disable weak ciphers via node

Tags: node.js, ssl

At the moment I am using https in production to create my server like this:

```
    var sslServerOptions = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('.', tlsServerConfig.key)),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('.', tlsServerConfig.cert))
        etc.
    };

    server = https.createServer(sslServerOptions, app);
```

Penetration testing has raised that some cyphers used by the application are not cryptographically secure.

can I configure this in the node code?

Comment: Check this out: https://certsimple.com/blog/a-plus-node-js-ssl